# Is there any way to know when an OnNext has been handled?

Tags: system.reactive

I have a pipeline setup all using reactive extensions, starting with a stream of values (could arrive any time they want) and then, subscribing to it there are many different "modules" outputting a stream of calculated values, and that stream is also subscribed to by another level of modules who also compute other values.

Now at the end of all this there is one class that listens to all those modules values and will output some other kind of value itself.

Now in normal life the initial stream of values arrive whenever, one by one.

But I also want to be able to "replay" those values and get all the outputs, but this time "as fast as possible".

But I still need those values to make sense, ie, that the final output could be "retraced" to the original value that generated it.

Not sure if I make sense here.

There are a few things I am considering, but none of which seem really clean.

One is to have "accelerated time". Ie have some kind of time warp and replay all, say, at 100x speed or whatever. This does have some significant drawbacks though, as in 100x speed then the time to process a value becomes much more significant.

The other one I was wondering (and leading to my question) about would be to be able to "step" all of this, ie to have a way to know when an OnNext has been fully handled by all its subscribers, so that I could just send one value in, wait for everybody to have handled it, get the corresponding output value, and then send the next one.

The would have the advantage that it could basically be replayed "as fast as my computer allows".

I was wondering if there was something I was missing, somewhere, or a way to do things that I had overlooked that could easily do what I want.

Failing that the only idea I could come up with was to have proxies/facades for all my classes so as to intercept every incoming and outgoing values and notify that so that my "replayer" would be able to trace it all.

---

I have probably formulated my question in a bad way. Let me rephrase.

My problem is not so much to "Replay" the values, I can do that just fine, even if just loading them from disk, and putting them into an IEnumerable, then they will be fed as fast as possible.

My problem is that, since all the pipeline is multi threaded in nature, if I send them just like that, as fast as possible, I will not have the ability to trace which input value generated which output value (unlike in your example, they would probably be intertwinned with each other).

I thought of the TimeStamped but it is not useful to me for several reasons:

1. The resolution of the TimeStamped is pretty much that of DateTime.Now, ie 10 ms which is not precise enough and
2. again, in a time based approach, if my pipeline takes,say, 5 msec to process, then all of a sudden this 5 msec takes too much meaning (like, in 5 msec probably a lot of input values would have already come in, making it impossible to know which one generated which output value).

I know this all sounds very "vague" and it definitely lacks a small sample, but I can't put my whole code in there as it is too long and complex, I will try at some point to get some small example going.

All of this is for a "simulation" environment, where I can replay yesterday's values and retrace what happened and when, but I could replay them faster.

Thanks a lot for your response though.

Comment: Have you looked at the virtual time additions to Rx?  http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Wes-Dyer-and-Jeffrey-Van-Gogh-Inside-Rx-Virtual-Time/ may help you get an idea of what to do.

Comment: All right. Watched the video. Wow. EXACTLY what I was looking for. Not only will this solve my problem, and in an elegant manner if you please, but hearing him talk about guys in finance and their problems with historical data and stuff it seems it is going to solve a lot of people's concrete problems. This really finished convincing me (if needed) that this isn't some kind of "astronaut's vaporware" but is going in the right direction and is well worth investing the little bit of effort/investment into it. Thanks for the link, I will post code when I get this working.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of how you end up using it if you get the chance.  You could post to the Rx Devlabs forums also, if you need more help or want to help the cause.  I haven't been able to get into that part of Rx yet and would like to see more examples of real usage.

Comment: Haven't you considered "threading" the original input value through the whole pipeline? You could pass a pair of values instead of just the result of the latest calculation.

Comment: @Big, Rx is here to stay. Once you "grok" it, old code seems just silly. Imagine if someone said you could not use Lamdas, Generics, Unit Tests or Resharper any more. Before you had them, they didn't seem that ground breaking, but take them away and you realise their power. Rx is that. Hard to initially get, then once you have it...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to perfectly replicate your multi threaded environment with a replay it will either be simple or impossible. (Silly statement I know).
1) If your worflow introduces concurrency, ie you have multiple schedulers or threading side effects (bad) between the source sequence producing the value and the final consumption of the value; then you will not have any luck. Once you add scheduluing and threading, you will not get the accurancy you are looking for (5ms).
2) If however you are only applying scheduling by the final consumer (ie using SubScribeOn & ObserveOn only once in the whole chain) and you also avoid any threading/scheduling or side effect constructs in your pipeline; then you are in for some good news.

Follow the guidelines that you only introduce concurrency/scheduling on the final subscriber and you can easily just use the VirtualScheduler/TestScheduler to control time. It should work like a dream and you can get time speed up but still have the luxury of Rx sequential gaurantees.

These links to my blog may help too:

http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/06/rx-part-6-scheduling-and-threading.html

http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/10/rx-part-8-testing-rx.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements here you want to be able to replay your observable stream of values without the original delay between each pushed value. If that's right then isn't this then a case when the `Replay` extension method can be used?

```
IConnectableObservable<TSource>
    Replay<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source);
```

Here's the test code I put together to check the behaviour:

```
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

Action<string, int> writeLine = (t, n) =>
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} @ {2} seconds",
        t, n,
        sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000"));

var source = Observable
    .GenerateWithTime<int, int>
    (0, n => n < 5, n => n + 1, n => n,
    n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

var replay = source.Replay();

using (var replayConnect = replay.Connect())
{
    Action sourceFinally = () =>
    {
        replay.Run(n => writeLine("Replay", n));
    };
    source.Finally(sourceFinally).Run(n => writeLine("Source", n));
}
```

The output from running this code is:

```
Source: 0 @ 1.094 seconds
Source: 1 @ 2.115 seconds
Source: 2 @ 3.129 seconds
Source: 3 @ 4.143 seconds
Source: 4 @ 5.158 seconds
Replay: 0 @ 5.199 seconds
Replay: 1 @ 5.201 seconds
Replay: 2 @ 5.201 seconds
Replay: 3 @ 5.201 seconds
Replay: 4 @ 5.201 seconds
```

If you need to know when the original values were pushed you can use the `Timestamp` extension method to change the observable from `IObservable<T>` to `IObservable<Timestamped<T>>`.

```
IObservable<Timestamped<TSource>>
    Timestamp<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source);
```

I can't tell if you've smoked too much pot, but does that help you to "detox"? ;-)